# Exchange 2007 Push Notifications not being received from Godaddy Hosted Exchange

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I've configured a client to subscribe to Push Notifications from a Godaddy Hosted Exchange 2007 SP1 server via EWS Managed API.

I can successfully request and then receive a Subscription ID from GoDaddy's server (mail.ex1.secureserver.net) but then don't receive *any* push notifications. I've contacted GoDaddy to make sure EWS Push Notifications aren't disabled, and according to them, they aren't; so, the problem must be in my listener service.

I am subscribing to the `DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.inbox` folder and to the following events: `NotificationEventTypeType.NewMailEvent`, `CopiedEvent`, `CreatedEvent`, `DeletedEvent`, `ModifiedEvent`, and `MovedEvent`.

The `SendNotification` method is never run:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
public class PushNotificationClient : WebService, INotificationServiceBinding

    [WebMethod(Description="Creates a push notification subscription")]
    public string Subscribe(){/* code to subscribe goes here. It seems to work perfectly and I receive a SubscriptionID, Watermark, and no error messages. */}

    public SendNotificationResultType SendNotification(SendNotificationResponseType sendNotification)
    {
        // this never happens
        WriteEventToLog("SendNotification happened!");
    }
}
```

The web service is publicly accessible at the URL specified in the Pull Subscription Request (`http://my-sub-domain.my-site.com/Service.asmx`). I've verified that POSTing to the URL manually does work as expected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that the SSL cert not being trusted will matter. Try subscribing to it using an http url instead. In theory you're not sending sensitive data over the wire, as you have to call back to get the data if memory serves correctly.

Comment: No luck on the http verison either. :-/ Any idea what HTTP verb I should be expecting here, and what will the actual URL will be?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything with EWS, but if memory serves you should expect a POST request to the web service URL. Have you tried the resources at https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/? That's quite a useful Microsoft resource

Comment: You are correct, it is a POST request. I created a mock POST request myself and sent it to my server it was worked fine, so it would seem that GoDaddy is just not sending them (or my subscription code is wrong).

Comment: testexchangeconnectivity.com Subscribes to PULL Notifications only; they don't even attempt to test PUSH. :-(

Comment: My next piece of advice would be to check the IIS server logs and see if any requests are being made.

Comment: I have. No requests of any kind, except my test requests, are made. ;(

Comment: I'm out of suggestions I'm afraid. If nothing is showing up in the server logs then it's either got to be firewall at your end (is the port being forwarded) or GoDaddy's end.

Comment: Update: GoDaddy shared hosting doesn't support PUSH Notifications, even though they will say they do when you call tech support.